# How to create customized "google search bar" gifs

Tags: 16.04, firefox, screenshot, google, gif

I am using Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04.

What is the best way to create customized "google search bar" gifs like [this one](https://giphy.com/gifs/search-MgcCwh5dTh6AE/fullscreen)?

Is there a software for doing this? A website? Or should I just record my screen activity? (if latter, any tips/software suggestions are welcome).

Answer (score 2):

Gif you linked to is nothing more than mere screen activity capture.
You use any screen capture software to record an .avi file then you can use converter like [this one](https://download.cnet.com/123-AVI-to-GIF-Converter/3000-2194_4-10392619.html) to create gif file. Unfortunately, because of nature of gif files your video get muted because gif files does not supports audio.

Hope I helped. Have luck with your problem.